# Why does IPAddress sometimes throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#

I was just trying to debug the following exception:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: newAddress
   at System.Net.IPAddress..ctor(Int64 newAddress)
```

This is the code in question:

```
int hostToNetworkOrder = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder( (int)computer.IpAddress );
IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress( hostToNetworkOrder );
```

`computer.IpAddress` is set to `1582281193`. This gets converted to `hostToNetworkOrder`, which is `-374255778`.

Now, if I try to construct `new IPAddress( -374255778 );` in the Immediate Window in Visual Studio, I get an IPAddress object containing the correct IP address.

But if I step over the line in the code, it will **always** throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Why?

---

### Update

I was aware that my input being negative was, most likely, the source of this issue. This is how I solved it:

```
UInt32 hostToNetworkOrder = (UInt32)IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder( (Int32)computer.IpAddress );
IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress( hostToNetworkOrder );
```

What I still don't understand is why it worked at all in the Immediate Window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the IPAddress class in ILSpy there is an internal constructor that takes an int and does not do an argument out of range check - I have a feeling that it may be calling that constructor in the watch window but in the actual code it calls the public ctor(long), which does validate that number.

To test out my theory, I just tried this bit of code:

```
var ipAddress = (IPAddress) typeof (IPAddress)
                                        .GetConstructor(
                                            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                                            null,
                                            new[] {typeof (int)},
                                            null)
                                        .Invoke(new object[] {hostToNetworkOrder });
```

and, sure enough, the IPAddress class is constructed without error.

Comment: +1 nice investigation! Had been using JustDecompile to do the same thing - the Int32 constructor is internal whereas the Int64 constructor is public

Answer (score 3):

> What I still don't understand is why it worked at all in the Immediate Window.

This is the crux of your question.  What you are not counting on is somewhat oddish behavior of the debugger expression evaluator that's used to parse your expression in the Immediate Window.  This is best demonstrated with a sample solution with code that behaves like IPAddress.  Create a console mode project and add a class library project.  Make the class library source code file look like this:

```
using System;

namespace Foo {
    public class Test {
        public string how;
        internal Test(int arg) { how = "internal"; }
        public Test(long arg) { how = "public"; }
        public string ToString() { return how; }
    }
}
```

And the Program.cs file of the console app like this:

```
using System;
using Foo;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        new Test(999);
    }   // <== set breakpoint here
}
```

Press F5 and switch to the Immediate window when the breakpoint hits.  Type:

```
new Foo.Test(-1).ToString()
```

And you'll see:

```
"internal"
```

**It picked the *internal* constructor over the public one**

Same thing that happened with IPAddress, it has an internal constructor that accepts an int which doesn't check the argument.  While this quacks loudly like a bug, providing access to private and internal members is normal debugger behavior.  In general, always keep in mind that the debugger expression evaluator is *not* driven by the C# compiler.  It doesn't use the exact same rules as the language and doesn't have the full expressiveness as the language.  Hopefully that will improve some day after project Roslyn completes.

Answer (score 1):

You get an `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` when the ip address is below zero or above 0x00000000FFFFFFFF, as seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13180abx.aspx).

The IPAddress constructor takes a parameter of type long (a 64bit integer), but you are passing it a 32bit integer which gets converted to a long.

Comment: That's what I assumed. But why did it work when constructing the object in the Immediate Window?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, I was converting the IP to int32:

```
    Int32 IP1 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP[0]);
    Int32 IP2 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP[1]);
    Int32 IP3 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP[2]);
    Int32 IP4 = Convert.ToInt32(arrIP[3]);
    long ipInt = IP1 + (IP2 * 256) + (IP3 * 256 * 256) + (IP4 * 256 * 256 * 256);
    IPAddress ipadr = new IPAddress(ipInt);
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(ipadr, port);
```

It was converting to negative number for some IPs.
The only change I did was using int64 and it solved my problem.

```
        Int64 IP1 = Convert.ToInt64(arrIP[0]);
        Int64 IP2 = Convert.ToInt64(arrIP[1]);
        Int64 IP3 = Convert.ToInt64(arrIP[2]);
        Int64 IP4 = Convert.ToInt64(arrIP[3]);
```